# Crontab Linux not running at specific time

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a crontab job that will running at 07.00 every day.
i already set it

```
0 7 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://localhost//blablaba
```

it did not work

but if i replace it with

```
    */10 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://localhost//blablaba
```

then its running every 10 minutes. but its not working if i give a specific time

for your information, i have check the server time and it shows the right time

Thanks for your help :(

Comment: you want to run it twice a day i mean at 7pm and 7am ?

Comment: just once at 7am. but its not running. if i set it every 10 minutes then its work @jilesh

Comment: please try this * 7 * * * /path_to_your_script    in place of  0 7 * * * /path_to_your_script

Comment: i tried this * 13 * * * but it still didnt work @jilesh

Comment: so plese check your url i think any mistake to define it in your server

Comment: @jilesh, with `* 7 * * *` it should run every minute between 07:00 upto 07:59 each day.  I think this is not what is being asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your cron expression looks correct.
As it follows this format:

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week [user] command
  0     7       *          *       *              /usr/bin/curl http://localhost//blablaba
```

**PS:** You need to add a user field if your are using the /etc/crontab file and not a  user specific crontab.

So, if your cron job is defined in the `/etc/crontab` file, then you need to add a user field to your cron job to make it run. If it's not the case, then check your URL on the client and server side.

But, I think the best thing to do would be debugging the cron job. SO, you need to enable logging for cron jobs by doing the following:

If you are on `Ubuntu`:

```
sudo vi /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

If you are on `CentOS`:

```
sudo vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Uncomment this line if it is commented:

```
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
```

Then restart rsyslog and cron:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
sudo service cron restart or sudo service crond restart
```

Now you can check the `/var/log/cron.log` file for log messages and see if there are any problems.

Comment: `sudo service cron restart` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you specify time, crontab take it according to UTC(Coordinated Universal Time) TimeZone.
So in order to work for your system you should specify it according to your timezone, or you can convert your specific time in command according to UTC.

For example:
my timezone is JST, and i want to run this file everyday at JST 15:00. so first i have to convert this time to UTC. it will look like this -

0 6 * * * python code.py (note : time is convert from JST 15:00 to UTC 6:00)

so this will execute my file at exactly 3pm everyday according to my timezone (JST)

Answer (score -1):

You Can Also Try this
You Have to Check Your Server Time in phpMyAdmin
Step 1 : Click On the phpMyAdmin.
Step 2 : Without Selecting The DataBase/ table Run this
SQL query  "SELECT NOW()"

Here You will get current time of your server in 24 Hrs Format. Now you can set cron job according to server time.